# My </form> tag disappears when I load the page in a browser, this results in my form not working, any ideas why?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, tags

My  tag disappears  when I load the page in a browser, this results in my form not working, any ideas why? I have tried different browsers but I get the same results.

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){

header("location: login/loginform.php");

 }else{

echo "Du är inloggad som " . $_SESSION["username"]; 
}

?>
<html>

<head

<meta charset="utf-8">

</head> 

<body

<form action="registerProduct.php" method="post">
    Namn: <input type="text" name="prodName"><br>
    Artikelnummer: <input type="text" name="prodNamenr"><br>
    Pris: <input type="text" name="prodPrice"><br>
    Bildlänk: <input type="text" name="prodImg"><br>
    Lagerstatus: <input type="text" name="prodStatus"><br>
    Beskrivning: <input type="text" name="prodDescrip"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: close head tag and body tag

Comment: Also close `<input></input>`.

Comment: I like more n-dru solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close your `<head>` and `<body>` tags!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  <body and <head
```

to

```
 <body> and <head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use valid markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

     <form action="registerProduct.php" method="post">
          Namn: <input type="text" name="prodName"><br>
          Artikelnummer: <input type="text" name="prodNamenr"><br>
          Pris: <input type="text" name="prodPrice"><br>
          Bildlänk: <input type="text" name="prodImg"><br>
          Lagerstatus: <input type="text" name="prodStatus"><br>
          Beskrivning: <input type="text" name="prodDescrip"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
     </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Also make sure that using [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) after [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) is a good habit, because php script does not immediately stops with executing after redirection.

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){

header("location: login/loginform.php");exit;

 }else{
//Note that printing anything before <html> tag will produce invalid markup 
echo "Du är inloggad som " . $_SESSION["username"];
}
```

?>